# Not being able to add multiple child views to parent view

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater

I am trying to add multiple relative layouts to a Linear layout. I am using the following lines of code.

```
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.reviews);

        for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
            View child = inflator.inflate(R.layout.review_item, null);
            child.setId(i);
            child.setTag(i);
            item.addView(child);
        }
```

But I can only see one child view. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: What is the orientation of ur linear layout??

Comment: reference ur linear parent layout only once, put it outside for loop and also inflater.

Comment: @DJphy orientation was horizontal. I made it vertical and it worked. Thankyou. Can you post it as answer.

Comment: No need it worked right thats enough and also follow the comment that i have made/the answer in the below post. That should  do, happy coding....

Comment: @DJphy I did follow the comment and thankyou once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `LinearLayout item` outside of the for loop.
The way you're doing it the variables value will be overwritten each time you run through the for loop. So your method should look like this:

```
public void somemethod(){

     LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.reviews);
     for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
        {

            View child = inflator.inflate(R.layout.review_item, null);
            child.setId(i);
            child.setTag(i);
            item.addView(child);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the first two lines outside of the for loop. You're inflating the LinearLayout twice, which overrides the first layout you inflate, rather than adding to it. By putting those two lines before the for loop starts, you'll add both child views to a single LinearLayout.